# How to use GPU to aclerate DNN forward function in opencv for sharp

Tags: c#, gpu

I have use OpenCVForUnity and opencvforsharp to implement Enet neural network for segmentation.I want to acelerate it forward function, how can Iuse my gpu to acelerate it.

I have used `setPreferableTarget(Dnn.DNN_TARGET_OPENCL);` but it is too slow

```
var enetmodel = "enet-model.net";

enet = Dnn.readNet(enetmodel);
var file = "example_01.png";
var org = Imgcodecs.imread(file);

var blob = Dnn.blobFromImage(org, 1.0 / 255, new Size(1024, 512));
enet.setPreferableBackend(3);
enet.setPreferableTarget(Dnn.DNN_TARGET_OPENCL);

enet.setInput(blob);
Mat score = enet.forward();
```

So I want ask for some other way to use nvidia to acelearate the forward function.
Thank you for attention.

Comment: [CUDA backend for OpenCV DNN](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/14827) was merged into master two days ago. Build the master branch and use `DNN_BACKEND_CUDA` as backend and `DNN_TARGET_CUDA` or `DNN_TARGET_CUDA_FP16` as targt.

Comment: Amazing ,I will have a try.Thank you very much